# Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

The error is in the question I did everything the error log told me to fix it but it did not fix so I am asking you now:

1. imported the `io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage` module in your **MainApplication.java** file.
2. Added the `new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()` line inside of the RN `getPackages()` method list.

```java
import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage());
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

Comment: Did you reinstall the app after linking this module?

Comment: what do you mean with reinstall

Comment: When ever you add native module. You need to run `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: when I do this the JS Server starts and does not do anything anymore. Is there a way to resync in like with android studio ?